# How can I resolve image paths in views that are part of a module based on the Composite Application Guidance using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, composite

I have a Silverlight application with several modules, which each resides in its own project. Unfortunately, all the paths used in images aren't resolved anymore (no pictures are shown in my Silverlight application).

Anyone a clue how to set image paths using the Composite Application Guidance in Silverlight for views residing in modules?

Comment: Where are the images located? Web? Included in one of the projects as Content or Resource? Other? Could you give an example of a full image tag?

Comment: Sure, the images are part of the Silverlight application as resources. e.g /Resources/myimage.png I'm trying to use this images (common images shared for all modules) from modules which live in their own assemblies. Let's assume I have a view in the root of a module assembly I have tried to reference the image as following: <image Source="/Resources/myimage.png"/> but it can't find the image. Everything works if I have the resources as part of the module but obviously I don't want to duplicate common images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've found the answer myself. Here it is:

```
<image Source="/MyAssembly;component/Resources/myimage.png" />
```